# Why is string interpolation not working in React Native?

Tags: javascript, react-native, image, string-interpolation

I want to dynamically choose a weather icon based on the conditions using string interpolation. For some reason this is not working in React Native.  Please tell me what I am missing. I have done the exact same thing with React so I don't understand why it isn't working in native.

If I do this for a specific image it works...

```
  setIcon(require(`./Icons/day/113.png`))
```

When I try and get the image dynamically it is not working...(pic gets the name of the image from the api)

```
  const pic = response.data.current.condition.icon.slice(-7);
  setIcon(require(`./Icons/day/${pic}`))
```

Then I am rendering the image like this....

```
      <View>
    <Image
      source={icon}
    />
    </View>
```

Comment: if your image is a url you need to pass an object with the uri field inside the source attribute for it to work in React Native.

Comment: Is it not missing .png at the end?

Comment: The variable is getting the last 7 characters for the icon in the api. For example it would be 113.png on a sunny day so the .png is included in the variable. The path is going to the icons I have saved in my project folders